# Mysql select query until reach the condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, limit

Lets say I have list of users in my user table like below. I need to find the count of users from my table until the `userid` is equal to **100**.

So here the answer is (3). But how can i find this is MySQL query. Any idea?

```
userid    name
---------------
10        aaa
30        bbb
100       ccc
60        ddd
```

Comment: Is the `UserId` field indexed anyhow?

Comment: Or is your query ordered by any other field?

Comment: if your table only has 2 columns, why userid is not sorted?

Comment: Actually my requirement is different. I suppose to find the user's rank from the score table. Scores not is order, so based on order by score DESC, i need to find the user rank. Here i have the userid. So by passing the userid i need this condition.

Comment: Isn't `userid` supposed to be unique across the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to do in MySql as the 'first' instance of a number can be difficult to pin down.

One way to resolve this would be to create row numbers, then choose the minimum row number with Userid = 100

```
select min(row_number) from
(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       p.*
FROM p,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
  ) g
where userid = 100
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/EHL57490)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much :).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the work around to achieve your expectation.

```
SET @row_number:=0;

SELECT A.row_number FROM (
    SELECT Userid, name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number  
    FROM UserDetail
) AS A
WHERE A.Userid = 100;
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://rextester.com/YIVH65096)</kbd>

In case if the `UserId` is the not the unique id and it can repeat, you may add the `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`

```
SET @row_number:=0;

SELECT A.row_number FROM (
    SELECT Userid, name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number  
    FROM UserDetail
) AS A
WHERE A.Userid = 100
ORDER BY A.row_number
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://rextester.com/TJAB79212)</kbd>

Sample execution with given data:

```
--DROP TABLE UserDetail;

CREATE TABLE UserDetail (Userid INT,  name VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO UserDetail (Userid, name) VALUES
(10 , 'Aaa'),
(30 , 'Bbb'),
(100, 'Ccc'),
(60 , 'ddd');

SET @row_number:=0;

SELECT A.row_number FROM (
    SELECT Userid, name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number  
    FROM UserDetail
) AS A
WHERE Userid = 100;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more than one instances of UserID = 100, you will need to choose the min value.  But great solution!  We must have been working on this at the exact same time!

Comment: @EoinS: Thought of the `UserId` is the unique, anyway handled the duplicate `Userid` by `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`